# spring and dynamic object creation

Tags: spring

i have a hierarchy of classes that generate some PDF invoices. Basically all classes implements a interface that has all the necessary methods for an invoice to be generated.
The problem is that concrete class that needs to be instantiated is determined at run time, because the class names for every client are stored in database.
Right now i have something like this in place :

```
    String pdfProcessorClass = "PdfParserXXX";
    pdfProcessorClass = pdfProcessorClass.trim();
    Invoic2Pdf pdfGenerator;
    try {
            Class<?> forName = Class.forName(pdfProcessorClass);
            pdfGenerator= (Invoic2Pdf) forName.newInstance();
            pdfGenerator.init(xXx, yYy);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          //deal with exception
        }
```

is there a posibility to achieve this in a more elegant way using Spring IoC taking into consideration that these classes that needs to be dynamically created are spring beans themselves ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's `IoC` features mostly come from the [`BeanFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) interface.

This interface and none of its implementations (AFAIK) have any methods for creating a bean from a String class name. So you would have to parse and use `Class.forName(String)` to get the `Class` instance anyway.

You could use Spring to create the bean once you have that class.

```
Class<?> forName = Class.forName(pdfProcessorClass);
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("yourContext.xml");
pdfGenerator = context.getBeanFactory().createBean(forName);
```

Or the overloaded `createBean()` method. Take a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#createBean%28java.lang.Class,%20int,%20boolean%29) for details.